# LaTeX typesetting question

Tags: numbering

I am writing Thesis. After all the chapters, I am including only one Appendix at the end of the Thesis without any sections. I want equation numbers of the Appendix as (A.0.1), (A.0.2), etc. And theorem numbers as Theorem A.0.1 , Theorem A.0.2 , etc.

Please reply me

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you any MWE to show what you have and what you want?

Comment: Welcome. I'm afraid we can't answer your question without more information about your document including the class and any packages you are using to manage sections/numbering in the thesis. Can you post a small, compilable document demonstrating the skeleton of your thesis and illustrating how you want this to work? Also, please edit your question title: on a site dedicated to TeX and friends, 90% of questions are about 'LaTeX typesetting'!

Comment: I don't know about theorems, but if you are using `\appendix` or the `appendix` package, the equation number changes automatically as "A.1" and so on.

Comment: zero counters do not look really nice

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what document class you are using I cannot guarantee that this will work. This example uses the `book` document class and the associated `\appendix` macro to establish that the author is finished with the book and is on to the appendices, subsequently each `chapter` is treated like an appendix. Also, you should heed the comment from @ChristianHupfer that "Zero counters do not look really nice," before incorporating this into your thesis.

You can achieve what you want by using `\renewcommand` to change `\theequation` label to reflect the various counters you want to display:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
   \chapter{a chapter}
    \lipsum{1}

    \chapter{another chapter}
    \lipsum{1}

    \appendix
    \chapter{an appendix}
    % put the following line in your document in the appendix
    \renewcommand\theequation{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
    \begin{equation}
        E = m c^2
        \label{eq:relativity}
    \end{equation}

    \chapter{another appendix}
\end{document}
```